# is there a way to prevent from a third party exe to kill my process in nsis

Tags: process, nsis

I'm running a third party executable within my nsis script which kills my process.

Is possible to prevent this ?

Comment: Could you give us some more information? In what way does the 3rd party exe kills your process? How do you call the process? Maybe there are command line parameters for the exe to change the behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user should be in control of their own machine and that means killing and/or debugging any process they want to.

The only way to prevent someone from killing your process would be to install some type of rootkit that prevents killing or hides the process from the process list but that would be evil so don't do it!

**Edit:**
What if you put one process between you and the script?

```
!define THESCRIPT "$sysdir\calc.exe"

Section
ExecWait '"cmd.exe" /c if 1==1 "${THESCRIPT}"'
SectionEnd
```

or

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh
Section
${GetParameters} $0
${GetOptions} "$0" "/DONTKILLME=" $1
${If} $1 != ""
        ExecWait '$1'
${Else}
        ExecWait '"$exepath" /DONTKILLME="${THESCRIPT}"'
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Ok, so it is not helping me. Thanks.

Comment: My problem is that the third party exe i'm running within my script is closing me.I want to prevent it.

Comment: It does not make much sense for a script to do this.